# CIImage saturation using CIFilters, is it possible?

Tags: objective-c, cifilter, ciimage

I am working with CIImage object, trying to get saturation value. But I cannot find the way to get image saturation, at least using CIFilters available in OS X.
Is it possible to get saturation of CIImage using standard CIFilters?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at `CIColorControls` filter. With this filter it is possible to adjust image's  saturation, brightness, and contrast.

> To calculate saturation, this filter linearly interpolates between a
>   grayscale image (saturation = 0.0) and the original image (saturation
>   = 1.0). The filter supports extrapolation: For values large than 1.0, it increases saturation.

Example:

```
CIFilter *colorControlsFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorControls"];
[colorControlsFilter setDefaults];
[colorControlsFilter setValue:sourceImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
[colorControlsFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0] forKey:@"inputSaturation"];
[colorControlsFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.2] forKey:@"inputBrightness"];
[colorControlsFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0] forKey:@"inputContrast"];

CIImage *outputImage = [colorControlsFilter valueForKey:@"outputImage"];
```

▸ `CIColorControls` reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIColorControls). 
▸  All CIFilters [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html).

Comment: Yes, Justin, this way one can change or set desired saturation. But I need to extract saturation from CIImage as a standalone grayscale image.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it using built-in CIFilter but you can code it quite simply. I won't give you full implementation but I can give you the cikernel that'll do the work :

```
vec4 rgbToHsv(vec4 rgb) {
    float x = min(rgb.r, min(rgb.g, rgb.b));
    float v = max(rgb.r, max(rgb.g, rgb.b));
    float f = (rgb.r == x) ? rgb.g - rgb.b : ((rgb.g == x) ? rgb.b - rgb.r : rgb.r - rgb.g);
    float i = (rgb.r == x) ? 3.0 : ((rgb.g == x) ? 5.0 : 1.0);
    float h = i - (f / (v - x));
    float s = (v - x) / v;
    return (v == x) ? vec4(-1, 0, v, rgb.a) : vec4(h, s, v, rgb.a);
}

kernel vec4 saturationToGrayscale(sampler image) {
    vec4 color = sample(image, samplerCoord(image));
    vec4 hsv = rgbToHsv(color);
    return premultiply(vec4(vec3(hsv.g), color.a));
}
```

rgbToHsv function comes from [Andy Finnell's blog](http://losingfight.com/blog/2007/01/26/image-filter-theatre-hsb-mixer/)

Output result is a grayscale image where white means sat == 1.0 and black means sat == 0.0. You can revert this by using "1.0-hsv.g" instead of "hsv.g" in the return argument.
You can also retrieve hue and value by using respectively hsv.r and rsv.b.

Making it a CIFilter is left to you. Take a Look at Apple's [Creating Custom Filters](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_custom_filters/ci_custom_filters.html) to do this. The code above takes place in the .cikernel file.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the saturation of an RGB image by converting it to YpCbCr and changing the `cb` and `cr` values. Accelerate.vimage can do this conversion for you, and Apple has a sample code project discussing that very topic [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vimage/real-time_video_effects_with_vimage).

You can wrap vImage operations in a `CIImageProcessorKernel` to make them available to Core Image. Again, Apple has an article explaining how to do that [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vimage/reading_from_and_writing_to_core_video_pixel_buffers).

Hope that helps,

simon